# Jenkins Job DSL - load groovy library from git repo

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to keep my seed job as small as possible and keep all the logic in a central git repository. Also, I have several independent Jenkins instances that then could share the code. How can I load a groovy library in a Jenkins Job DSL script?

Is there something like the [Pipeline Remote File Loader Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin), so that you only need to do `fileLoader.fromGit('lib.groovy', 'https://git.repo')`?

Answer (score 1):

Hereafter my quicksheet about achieving this in a parameterized Pipeline job,
Using Pipeline script from SCM from git.repo

What may be of interest to you:

- loading mecanism : `stash/unstash`
- "from SCM" location : `src = "../${env.JOB_NAME}@script/"`

**Jenkins**

```
Pipeline
    Definition:        "Pipeline script from SCM"
    SCM:               Git
    Repository URL     git.repo
    Branches to build  */master
    Script Path        jobs/build.groovy
This project is parameterized:
    String Parameter   PARAM0
    String Parameter   PARAM1
```

**git.repo**

```
├── jobs
│   ├── helpers
│   │   └── utils.groovy
│   └── build.groovy
└── scripts
    ├── build
    │   └── do_build.sh
    └── inc.sh
```

Contents : utils.groovy

```
├── jobs
│   ├── helpers
│   │   └── utils.groovy
def log(msg) {
    println("========== " + msg)
}
return this
```

Contents : build.groovy

```
├── jobs
│   └── build.groovy
stage ('Init') {
    /* Loads */
    def src                 = "../${env.JOB_NAME}@script/"
    def helpers_dir         = 'jobs/helpers'
    def scripts_dir         = 'scripts'
    /* Stages Scripts */
    def do_build            = 'build/do_build.sh'
    utils                   = load src + helpers_dir + "/utils.groovy"
    dir(src) {
        stash name: scripts_dir, includes: "${scripts_dir}/"
    }
}
stage ('Build') {
    node () {
        unstash scripts_dir
        build_return = sh (returnStdout: true, script: """
            ./${scripts_dir}/${do_build} \
            "${PARAM0}" \
            "${PARAM1}"
        """).readLines()
        builded = build_return.get(build_return.size()-1).tokenize(',')
        utils.log("PARAM0: " + builded[0])
        utils.log("PARAM1: " + builded[1])
    }
}
```

Contents : inc.sh

```
└── scripts
    └── inc.sh
#!/bin/sh
## scripts common includes
common=included
```

Contents : do_build.sh

```
└── scripts
    ├── build
    │   └── do_build.sh
#!/bin/sh
## includes
. $(dirname $(dirname ${0}))/inc.sh
echo ${common}
## ${0} : PARAM0
## ${1} : PARAM1
echo "${0},${1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Job DSL Gradle Example](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example) shows how to maintain DSL code in a Git repository.